# How can I trigger an azure logic application on more than one triggers?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am currently designing an Azure Logic App integrating our organization's Sharepoint and CRM end points. I need to execute same set of steps whenever a new file is created on a sharepoint site, or whenever an existing file is modified. Currently, I am able to trigger the app only on either of these actions, but not on both. I think this is by design. But is there anyway to trigger a logic app on both these actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add multiple triggers but not through the UI. This is currently supported only in codeview.
 
Example. Multiple triggers in LA

```
"triggers": {
    "Recurrence": {
        "recurrence": {
            "frequency": "Minute",
            "interval": 5
        },
        "type": "Recurrence"
    },
    "When_a_new_tweet_is_posted": {
        "inputs": {
            "host": {
                "api": {
                    "runtimeUrl": "https://logic-apis-westus.azure-apim.net/apim/twitter"
                },
                "connection": {
                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['twitter']['connectionId']"
                }
            },
            "method": "get",
            "path": "/onnewtweet",
            "queries": {
                "searchQuery": "#LogicApps"
            }
        },
        "recurrence": {
            "frequency": "Minute",
            "interval": 3
        },
        "splitOn": "@triggerBody()?.value",
        "type": "ApiConnection"
    }
}
```

Comment: As an alternative you can deploy the same logic app twice, one copy with the Sharepoint trigger, and one copy with the CRM trigger. This way you will still have full designer support.

Comment: @SzymonWylezol and have to maintain two apps instead of one?

Comment: yes, that's true @juunas, and that's why I am much reluctant to create two Logic Apps for the same purpose, except, the trigger. Maintaining two same apps isn't a good design. There is an option to call one logic app from another logic app (nested logic app), but it seems there arent good examples of it over internet.